# How to edit bootstrap button `pull-right` in REACT? It is not responding (using bootstrap v3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Im trying to have buttons on my article lists.  This is for saving the article.  But it wont move to the right.  I tried it and it worked but the buttons overlapped on top of each other.  So my approach then is to wrap it around a div container and give that div a `className=pull-right` . The newbie that I was - didnt work.  I hope someone can shed light on this - thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "../styles/style.css";
const Results = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container fluid">
      {/* line space */}
      <div>Search Results: </div>

      <ul className="list-group">
        {props.results.map(result => {
          return (
            <a href={result.url} onClick={result.handleArticleOnClick}>
              <li className="list-group-item" key={result.id}>
                {result.title}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className={styles.style}
                  onClick={result.handleSaveArticle}
                >
                  Save this
                </button>
              </li>
            </a>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Results;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear your floats.

```
    <li className="list-group-item clearfix" key={result.id}>
        ...
            <button
              type="button"
              className={`pull-right ${styles.style}`}
              onClick={result.handleSaveArticle}
            >
```

Answer (score 0):

How about turn li tag to a flex box:

```css
li{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
```

```html
<a>
  <li>
     <div>Some text</div>
     <button type="button">
       Save this
      </button>
  </li>
</a>
```

If you are using Bootstrap V4

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "../styles/style.css";
const Results = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container fluid">
      {/* line space */}
      <div>Search Results: </div>

      <ul className="list-group">
        {props.results.map(result => {
          return (
            <a href={result.url} onClick={result.handleArticleOnClick}>
              <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between" key={result.id}>
                {result.title}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className={styles.style}
                  onClick={result.handleSaveArticle}
                >
                  Save this
                </button>
              </li>
            </a>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Results;
```

Comment: It didnt work Kevin.  Still have the same result.  on top you said `i` tag? What is that mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean li element. :)

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap V4: <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between" key={result.id}>     If you are not, you can write some css for your li element as my first example.

Comment: I apologize, Im using version 3

Comment: So, you can give your li element some css like: display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

Comment: doesnt work Kevin - thats what I did earlier after you suggested that for version 4

Comment: Add css style does not matter what version of Bootstrap you are using. :) If you run my first code snippet, you will see. I did not use any library in that.